# I want to only call one event at time

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-handling, dom-events

I want to only call one  checkout--active and dummy-grid--highlight at time.

Right it works you can open them all and they will appear all on top of each other. So I need to use the prevent action: If one is already open and you open a new one then you close the old one and open the new one.

```
<div class="checkout">
  <a class="checkout__button" href="#">
    <!-- Fallback location -->
    <span class="checkout__text">
      <span class="checkout__text-inner checkout__initial-text">Testn</span>
    <span class="checkout__text-inner checkout__final-text"> </span>

    </span>
  </a>
  <div class="checkout__order">
    <div class="checkout__order-inner">
      <h1>test</h1>
      <p>
        test
      </p>
      <table class="checkout__summary">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

      </table>
      <!-- /checkout__summary -->
    </div>
    <!-- /checkout__order-inner -->
  </div>
  <button class="checkout__close checkout__cancel">Close</button>
  <!-- /checkout__order -->
</div>
```

```
(function() {
  var dummy = document.getElementById('dummy-grid');
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.checkout')).forEach(function(el) {
    var openCtrl = el.querySelector('.checkout__button'),
      closeCtrl = el.querySelector('.checkout__cancel');

    openCtrl.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault(removeEventListener);
      classie.add(el, 'checkout--active');
      classie.add(dummy, 'dummy-grid--highlight');
    });

    closeCtrl.addEventListener('click', function() {
      classie.remove(el, 'checkout--active');
      classie.remove(dummy, 'dummy-grid--highlight');
    });
  });
})();
```

```
var classie = { // full names   
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass, // short names   
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport 
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  // AMD   
  define(classie);
} else {
  // browser global   
  window.classie = classie;
}
```

I have been trying for so long and I have no clue how I am going to over come this matter. 
Help ?

Comment: There is no element with id dummy-grid in your html code. it's really unclear  to understand what's going wrong without seeing the complete code

Comment: This is the full demo http://tympanus.net/Development/CheckoutConcepts/rounded.html
There's no dummy-grid in HTML.